# Round off one edge of an image

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, manipulation

I want to round off the top left hand corner of an image as someone has simply removed pixels and it looks a mess on the site.

Can anyone possibly tell me how to achieve this in Photoshop?

Comment: Can you be a little bit clearer on your question?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "round off" the top corner? I would use the rounded box selector to create a corner the size of which I liked, then use that as a mask on the image to remove the corner.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to use the Rounded Rectangle select tool and match it up on the corner that you want to remove, then put the other corners outside the photo so that they don't round off any other corner. Then I would invert the selection and delete the selection.

Or you can try the nifty new content-aware fill feature in Photoshop perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pen tool to draw a curve over the corner you want to round off then delete those pixels, there should be many tutorials on using pen tool in photoshop around the 'nets if you dont know how.